# Line plot in GnuPlot where line width is a third column in my data file?

Tags: plot, graph, gnuplot

I have a datafile that has three columns :

```
1 1.0 1
2 1.5 2
3 0.0 3
4 1.2 2.5
5 1.0 1
6 1.1 5
```

where the first column is my X value, the second column is my Y value, and the third column is the line width.  I'd like for each line segment to be plotted according to the third column line width.

I tried:

```
plot 'file1.dat' using 1:2:3  with lines lw var
```

But I get undefined variable: var error.

Is this possible in gnuplot?

Thanks.

Comment: A line segment is between two points. Both specify a different line width. Which one should be used?

Comment: No in this form this is impossible with Gnuplot: as Christoph wrote there is an uncertainty what should be the line width so Gnuplot doesn't interpret "with lines lw variable".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define column 3 as the linewidth between points n and n+1 (so the value of col. 3 of the row will be ignored) you can cheat:

```
stat 'file1.dat'
n=STATS_records
plot for [i=0:0] 'file1.dat' using 1:2:(alma=$3) every ::i::i w l lc 1 lw 1
plot for [i=0:n-1] 'file1.dat' using 1:2:(alma=$3) every ::i::i+1 w l lc 1 lw alma notitle
```

OR

```
plot 'file1.dat' u 0:1
n=GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX
plot for [i=0:0] 'file1.dat' using 1:2:(alma=$3) every ::i::i w l lc 1 lw 1
plot for [i=0:n] 'file1.dat' using 1:2:(alma=$3) every ::i::i+1 w l lc 1 lw alma notitle
```

[image]

You need the first `plot for[i=0:0]` to 'initialize' variable 'alma'.

Comment: Good solution! So you've decided that the linewith for `[i, i+1]` was the one in line `i`, maybe it's good to state it explicitly. Next there'll be a question to make tapered lines between two points!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Indeed, you are right, the n dots create n-1 segments with width. I will consider the 0th width as 1 then.

Comment: @Joce you want to kill me, don't you? :D

Comment: @Joce I thought about using `filledcurves` for the tapered lines, but my results were wrong, because the line width must be applied vertically to the connecting lines, and not on the y-axis only.

Comment: @Christoph: I'm not sure I get what the problem is, of course in any tapered broken line there is the question of how the connection is made at nodes, and having the taper along `y` rather than the normal will distort things when slope is large, but I'd think it'd still look OK? Or else one could calculate the y-equivalent of a normal taper, and add circles of correct radius at nodes! A summer of code project, nearly!

Comment: @TomSolid: BTW, why `alma` ? Your university, your girlfriend's name, your latin soul, a Hungarian apple or some mysterious abbreviation? :)

Comment: @Joce: 'alma' as 'apple' : ) Naming the variables after fruits in ABC order: 'apple, banana, lemon, walnut, strawberry...' (alma, banán, citrom, dió, eper) :D

Comment: @JoceNoToPutinsWarInUkraine tapered lines are not impossible (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73485567/7295599), but it requires gnuplot5.2. I haven't found yet a solution for the version at the time of OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Christoph in the comments, you have `N` points (rows) and `N` linewidth values, but only `N-1` connecting lines.
So, you have to decide which linewidth value should be applied to which line. Which one to skip? The first one or the last one? Here, the last one is skipped.

It's basically, a shortened version of @Tom Solid's solution. Actually, you can get the initial value already during the `stats` command.

As @Joce mentioned and @Ilya Zakharevich is suggesting in his answer, if you do not fear some extra effort you can also [draw tapered lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73485567/7295599).

**Data:**

```
# x   y     linewidth
  1   1.0   1
  2   1.5   2
  3   0.0   3
  4   1.2   2.5
  5   1.0   1
  6   1.1   5
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot 4.6.0, March 2012)

```
### workaround for variable linewidth
reset

FILE = "SO/SO37925489.dat"

stats FILE u ((N=$0)==0?Lw0=$3:0) nooutput
set grid

plot for [i=0:N] FILE u 1:2:(Lw0=$3) every ::i::i+1 w l lw Lw0 lc rgb "red" notitle
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
stat 'varwidth.dat' nooutput
n=STATS_records; prex=0; prey=0; SC=2    # How y-axis is expanded relative to the x-axis
plot for [i=0:n-1] for [try=0:1] '' using 1:((try==0?dx=$1-prex:1),(try==0?sl=($2-prey)/(dx==0?1:dx):1),(try==0?prex=$1:1),(try==0?prey=$2:1),$2+(w=$3/80*sqrt(1+(SC*sl)**2))/2):($2-w/2) every ::i::i+1 w filledcurves lc 1 notitle
```

This produces the correct **line width** (as opposed to the “line height”, as in [the answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52267495/9106292)).  I have no clue how to make the “lines” match where they join (seems to be impossible without support from inside `gnuplot`).

(This assumes that the data in the question is in a file `varwidth.dat`.)
[image]